# generate .bbl file and citation problem

Tags: biblatex, citing, texstudio, ieeetran

I am using TexStudio and I am working with my university template.
The problem is, when I compile the FILE, I can not see `FILE.bbl` in document and also all my citations in the final PDF are shown like "[?]". How I can solve it?

Comment: You need to run BibTeX or Biber (which depends on the bibliography packages you load and their settings) in order to create a `.bbl` file. Usually you will run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ... and "BibTeX" could also be Biber as required). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. Sorry to be so vague, but you need to tell us more about your document and what you tried if you want more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running the LaTex from the terminal/command line.
run Latex by these commands:

1. latex FILE
2. bibtex FILE
3. latex FILE
4. latex FILE

The "FILE" is the name of your latex file. Also, at first, you should go to the Latex directory that all your files exist. Then, run the above comments.

Comment: This is the basic standard procedure to compile tex-files. In TeXstudio you may run Bibliography with `F8`.

Comment: Yes I used TeXstudio and I always compile it through software. When I wanted to change the template, all references where in the form of [?]. I tried various ways. Finally, based on above comment, I used terminal and it solved. While I deleted all files except .tex and run some times but it did not work. Just it needed to run via Terminal window.

Comment: Strange, deleting files (except the .tex) should correct/update any standard your `.aux`, `.bbl`, etc. have been made. Well, on the other hand, there is not a lot of to do since there was no MWE or log file.

Comment: Yes you are right, after deleting always everything renewed for me but this time....